# First Wort Hopping (or FWH)

Tags: hops, bittering, wort, boil, bitterness

What is First Wort Hopping (FWH) and how best can it be replicated in extract brewing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[First wort hopping](http://www.homebrewtalk.com/wiki/index.php/First%5Fwort%5Fhopping) is the practice of adding hops to kettle when you take first runnings from the mash tun.  As the kettle fills you heat the wort to boiling.  The "boil hops" are in the kettle before the boil begins and steep in the warm wort.

The best way to carry this over to extract brewing would be to add your first hops to the kettle when the wort reaches 150º-170ºF.